# ASP.NET MVC Running a console application to update a database

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a console application that seems to pull a url from an API and perform some database operations (i.e. update the database with content from the data within the API url). I want to perform this update so that it can update my database with the latest data. How can I do run this?

Sorry if this is a vague or silly question to ask but I am a complete noob with ASP.NET so not sure where to even start so would be great if somebody could help me and give me the basics on what to do.

Comment: Let me see if I can clarify.. You want your ASP.NET application to do the same thing that the console application is doing just within the webserver right?

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this within your console application.

```
void Main()
{
    //Create disposable WebClient
    using (var client = new WebClient())
    {
        //Get list of dynamic parameters
        string param = "value";

        //Use WebClient to Download the response as Json String
        var result = client.DownloadString("http://api.service.com/path/here/?param=" + param);

        //Deserialize JSON using Newtonsoft.Json
        MyClass obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyClass>(result);

        //Save Object to Db
        SaveToDb(obj);
    }
}

public void SaveToDb(MyClass obj)
{
    //Use whatever persistence you prefer
    using (var context = new DataContext())
    {
        context.MyClasses.Add(obj);
        context.SubmitChanges();
    }
}

// Define other methods and classes here
class MyClass
{
    public int MyClassID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```